# Replace each char after specific word with * using regex JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace each char after 'to' with * using regex in Java.

Input:

```
String str = "thisisstringtoreplace"
```

Expected output:

```
thisisstringto*******
```

I am using

```
Pattern.compile("(?<=password=).*$")
```

This pattern replace all char with 1 `*` , I want `*` of remaining sting size (7 in this case). The action I want to perform is part of framework so I just need a regex for this.

Comment: I will give you a clue [indexOf(String str)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

Comment: what about [`String[] split = str.split("to");
String result = split[0] + "to" + String.format("%0" + split[1].length() + "d", 0).replace("0", "*");`](https://ideone.com/oFGTvT)

Comment: Please let know what pattern you tried, it will be easier to see where you are wrong and help you better.

Comment: Actually the action I want to [erform is part of framework so I just need a regex for this

Comment: "I need" is not an appropriate problem statement. Your task is clear. What have you done to solve it?

Comment: Pattern.compile("(?<=password=).*$")

Comment: this pattern replace all char with 1 * , I want * of remaining sting size (7 in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\G(?!^)|to).", "*");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Lix4p/1/).

**Details**

- `(?<=\G(?!^)|to)`  - either the end of the previous successful match or `to`
- `.` - any char but a line break char.